How to Run next dev with Production .env.production Variables?
I'm working on a Next.js project and need to run the development server (next dev) using the production environment variables defined in my .env.production.local file. By default, next dev loads .env.development or .env.local, but I require production settings for specific testing scenarios. I know there's a way, i.e., next build -> next start, but for every change, I have to stop the server, rebuild the project, and restart the server, which is inefficient.
Desired Outcome:
Run next dev using .env.production variables to test production-specific configurations.
Ideally, I want to have two scripts in package.json:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "run_prod": "next dev" // loads up .env.production.local file instead of .env.development
}


Can you set NODE_ENV in your package script? Next should respond to this (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order).
run_prod: NODE_ENV=production next dev
Do be aware that you can't really get a production bundle out of next dev so you'd need to do next build && next start to really be sure everything works... but you'd at least get your faster dev cycle this way by avoiding the constant stop start of build && start.

this didn't work `⚠ You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment. This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised against. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env
▲ Next.js 14.2.5

Local:        http://localhost:3000
Environments: .env.development.local
Experiments (use with caution):
· scrollRestoration

✓ Starting...
✓ Ready in 1334ms
○ Compiling /app ...
✓ Compiled /app in 3.9s (1248 modules)
TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function
at `

Interesting. Are you using one of the three permitted values (development, production, & test) for NODE_ENV?
